# How to turn shadowing on in folds of 3D model?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have try to setup black shadow in depth areas of product in `ARKit` scene but do not success. I tried with this code:

```
node.geometry?.materials.first?.ambientOcclusion.contents = 0.5
```

I have attached required result image and current result image.

**Current Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image: expected result]

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450874/7512091

Comment: "ambient occlusion"... combined with estimating the lighting of the physical scene to map onto the virtual one

Answer (score 1):

### First Approach

The most robust and easiest way to work with ***self-shadowing*** and ***Ambient Occlusion*** for 3D models is to create a fake **`UV-mapped texture`** for that (rather than rendering self-shadowing in folds in realtime). So with fake AO texture on a 3D model a burden on CPU/GPU is minimal and your battery is very grateful to you, as well.

To create a UV-mapped Diffuse and Ambient Occlusion textures you need a `UV Texture Editor` that you can find in any popular 3D authoring application (like Maya or 3dsMax). After rendering UV-mapped AO texture (**as a four channel PNG file with a premultiplied alpha RGBxA**) you can simply assign it using this code:

```
node.geometry?.materials.first?.ambientOcclusion.contents = UIImage(named: "AO.png")
```

Look at these 2 uv-mapped textures stored in 2 different png files:

[image]

Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDXEvQdCEKk) to a 5 minute video on how to uv-map textures in Maya.

> **Or, as even more simple solution, you can paint a `UV-mapped Diffuse texture` in Photoshop-like app using semi-transparent black color brush**.

Then assign shadow-painted texture via `diffuse` slot:

```
node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "diffuseWithShadows.png")
```

[image]

[image]

### Second Approach

Or you can use [Fake Shadows technique](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c).

Comment: we do extra scaling while unwrapping UV's. So, occlusion map baked from maya or max will not support our process of creating and applying texture on 3d model.
So, it will be helpful if you can suggest any other alternative for generating Ambient Occlusion map.